# Grabbing Pixel Attributes In Python Using Tk Or Wx?

Tags: python, wxpython, pixel, tk-toolkit

I am using Python3 on Windows 7. I want to grab all the attributes like color intensity, color etc. Of all the pixels of the screen area that I select with mouse. The selection can be of any shape but right now rectangular and square will do. I want to do it in any area of the screen.

Can you guys please guide me how to do that in Python using Tk Or Wx(If I must use some GUI toolkit). ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have never used Wx or Tk, so I don't know how to do that using Wx or Tk. I would suggest that you use some image processing libraries. You can use **[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/)** or **[SimpleCV](http://simplecv.org/)** for this. It will be really easy if you use OpenCV or SimpleCV. SimpleCV is based on OpenCV but it's more user friendly and easy to work with.

Here's a SimpleCV example to get RGB values of the point where you click

```
from SimpleCV import *

def imagetest():
    i = Image("lenna")
    disp = Display()
    i.show()

    while disp.isnotDone():
        if disp.mouseLeft:  # mouse left click
            print i.getPixel(disp.mouseX, disp.mouseY)
```

similarly, you can take values of all the pixels that bind in a rectangle with starting point as your mouse click and pre defined value that you have provided for height and width of the rectangle.

Here's a code that I had worked out to make a line on an image when you click on two points. https://github.com/jayrambhia/SimpleCVexamples/blob/master/drawlines.py

You can find more SimpleCV examples here. https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/tree/master/SimpleCV/examples

Since SimpleCV is a library for Computer Vision, you might not find all the examples really helpful but you could try looking at some

Comment: I don't think this answer is very helpful unless you show an example of doing what the question asks how to do. Simply saying "use library X" isn't good enough.

Comment: okay. sorry. my bad. I have added a small example and few more links.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, wxPython isn't supported on Python 3 as of yet. Hopefully it will later this year. In the mean time, you'll probably have to blit your selection to a wx.Image or wx.MemoryDC and use the methods mentioned on this page: http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/wxPoint-and-Bitmap-pixel-color-value-td2294179.html

Basically, you call dc.GetPixel or image.GetRed, image.GetGreen, image,GetBlue.